# SonarQube ignore getter/setters in code analysis

Tags: sonarqube, getter, setter

Is there a setting in SonarQube dashboard that allows for ignoring getter and setters? This sounds like a better option then coding //nopmd on every method in your codebase.

My codebase has a lot of them and they are dramatically lowering my unit test coverage % being reported in the Sonarqube dashboard

Comment: Why do you want to ignore them? Which rule creates issues for that code?

Comment: My codebase has a lot of them and they are dramatically lowering my unit test coverage % being reported in the Sonarqube dashboard

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to ignore getters and setters. However, if you have classes you'd like omitted entirely from coverage calculations, you can easily do so with [exclusions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreCodeCoverage).