# Sonarqube getter and setter duplications

Tags: sonarqube, getter-setter

How can I configure my sonarqube analysis to ignore my getters and setters and not count them as duplicated line. Because I have them both on my entites and on my DTO class. So the duplications % is up to 15%.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331440/sonarqube-ignore-getter-setters-in-code-analysis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SonarQube ignore getter/setters in code analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331440/sonarqube-ignore-getter-setters-in-code-analysis)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, sonar do not provide many rules about getter/setter :
[image]

You can configure which files will be reviewed by sonarqube. This could be an exclusion by package or by class name.
For instance, you can exclude **com.company.business.plip.dto** by adding this to your `sonar-project.properties` :

```
sonar.exclusions=src/main/java/com/company/business/plip/dto/**
```

Considering your dto are just empty shells, containing only privated fields and getters/setters ; this wouldn't cause a huge impact to your code coverage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works fine. It's also possible to change that value after login on sonarqube server through Administration > Analysis Scope

Answer (score 0):

You can set exclusions specifically for duplications using this:
sonar.cpd.exclusions=src/main/java/com/company/business/plip/dto/**